# Is it possible to animate a TabView item with .symbolEffect?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I have a `TabView` and would like to animate one of the items

```
@State var isLoading = false

// ...

TabView {
    Color.blue
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "star")
                .symbolEffect(.pulse, options: .repeating, isActive: isLoading)
        }
}
```

Is it possible to do that with `.symbolEffect`? This works for without the tab item, but with it there's nothing happening.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to find some workaround for that. I've played a bit with it right now and found these 3 solutions:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var tabSelection: String = "star"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
                Text("Person")
                    .tag("person")
                
                Text("Star")
                    .tag("star")
            }
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
                HStack(spacing: 50) {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                        .symbolEffect(.pulse, options: .repeating, isActive: true)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                        .padding(.bottom)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            tabSelection = "person"
                        }
                    
                    Image(systemName: "star")
                        .symbolEffect(.pulse, options: .repeating, isActive: true)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                        .padding(.bottom)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            tabSelection = "star"
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Basically you would need to build your own Tab Bar using the `safeAreaInsets` modifier and placing the items at the `bottom` while also handling the user interactions there. This way you would preserve the `symbolEffect` animations.

**Other possible solutions:**

You may also use the `toolbar` modifier and placing the items in the `bottomBar`, but I 've found out this gives you little room for flexibility when it comes to placing items.

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
        Image(systemName: "person")
           .symbolEffect(.pulse, options: .repeating, isActive: true)
           .font(.title2)
           .foregroundStyle(.blue)
           .padding(.bottom)
           .onTapGesture {
               tabSelection = "person"
           }
      }
            
      ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
          Image(systemName: "star")
             .symbolEffect(.pulse, options: .repeating, isActive: true)
             .font(.title2)
             .foregroundStyle(.blue)
             .padding(.bottom)
             .onTapGesture {
                tabSelection = "star"
             }
        }
    }
```

A third solution involves applying an `overlay` at the bottom of the `TabView` like so:

```
.overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
    HStack(spacing: 50) {
        Image(systemName: "person")
             .symbolEffect(.pulse, options: .repeating, isActive: true)
             .font(.title2)
             .foregroundStyle(.blue)
             .padding(.bottom)
             .onTapGesture {
                 tabSelection = "person"
             }
                
         Image(systemName: "star")
            .symbolEffect(.pulse, options: .repeating, isActive: true)
            .font(.title2)
            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
            .padding(.bottom)
            .onTapGesture {
               tabSelection = "star"
            }
       }
 }
```

Let me know your thoughts on these 3 solutions!

Comment: Sadly all of these come with some drawbacks that are probably not worth it for animation, but I appreciate the effort :)

Comment: Drawbacks such as?

Comment: If you appreciate the effort, I would appreciate if you could at least upvote the answer. It's not even the first time I answer one of your questions...

Comment: Apologies, I should’ve given some more detail. All options are recreating the tab bar manually instead of using the `.tabItem` which I was hoping for. That means many things will look off or have to be reimplemented, such as the selection, label, badges, different looks on different platforms etc. Placement will probably never be the exact same. Your answer does get the job done though, so thanks again for taking the time :)